# Bluetooth (A2DP) Audio input device

Tags: audio, bluetooth, streaming

I use my Ubuntu (13.10) laptop as an A2DP (Bluetooth audio) sink for my Android phones. The music I play on my phones is sent to the laptop and is heard through laptop speakers. Now I'm trying to setup my laptop as a streaming server. I installed Icecast2 and Darkice. In the Darkice conf file, I configured audio input device as: default, pulse, hw:0,0, plughw:0,0 etc. In all cases, Darkice streams laptop microphone audio only and it does not stream Bluetooth PCM audio. When I muted the microphone in the Unity sound applet, Darkice streams only silence. To stream Bluetooth audio what device I should put in the Darkice conf file?

Comment: want this too. have you made any progress? i try to stream music from android phone to android TV box.
the box is on android 4.4 as lollipo could act as a2dp sink. so i would like to use a raspberry to receive an a2dp stream and forwand it as mpd to the android tv box.